# How to wirelessly connect TP-LINK TL-WA701ND with a THOMSON TG585v7 router from the ISP?

Tags: wireless-router, bridge-router

How can I wirelessly connect a TP-LINK TL-WA701ND with a THOMSON router from my ISP? The THOMSON is connected to Internet and I want to connect to it TP-LINK.

I tried do that using WDS on Thomson and client mode on TP-Link, but no success. How to connect them with WPA2?